# Querying the set of active CUDA kernels on a GPU

Tags: debugging, cuda

Is there a way to ask the GPU (or driver) to list the set of active (or dispatched or issued) CUDA kernels on a GPU, without attaching `cuda-gdb` to the owning CPU process and suspending it?

I'm imagining something like [pstack](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pstack), where the interface might look like:

```
> list-cuda-kernels $pid
gpu 0: kernel_foo
gpu 0: kernel_bar
gpu 1: kernel_baz
```

Comment: recent versions of nvidia-smi might do what you want on linux with a Tesla card.

Comment: @talonmies nvidia-smi can't list CUDA kernels

Comment: I'm using Fermi-based Tesla cards and as Eugene says, nvidia-smi only lists processes, not kernels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no tool or API to fetch list of the currently running kernels other then cuda-gdb (or any other CUDA debugger for that matter).